# why am I getting a 500 response?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm including below snippets from all the files.  I'm simply doing an import on all in all the various files for the models/serializers/views/etc.  I have other views based off of model serializers and they work fine but this one seems to be causing me grief and I don't know why.

My urls.py -

```
url(r'^deploy/resource/$', DeployResourceFilterView.as_view(), name='DeployResourceFilterView'),
```

views.py

```
class DeployResourceFilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        resname = self.request.GET.get('name')
        queryset = Resmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(resmst_name=resname)
        if queryset:
            return queryset
        else:
            raise Http404
```

serializers.py

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Resmst
        resource_name = 'resmst'
        depth = 1
```

models.py

```
class Resmst(models.Model):
    resmst_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column='resmst_id')
    resmst_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    resmst_desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    resmst_limit = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resmst_inuse = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resmst_active = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    resmst_lstchgtm = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    resmst_prntid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resmst_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, db_column='owner_id', verbose_name='owner')
    resmst_public = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    resmst_locked = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    resmst_offline = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'resmst'
```

I'm trying to hit `http://localhost:9001/deploy/resource/?name=thisisthename`

Something is being overlooked but I can't find what it could be.

Comment: Set `DEBUG=True` and see what Django has to tell you. You should see the traditional django error page with a lot of useful information.

Comment: awesome thanks!  Forgot I productionalized my site!  Seeing now it's complaining about a column in the DB Table.  I can troubleshoot from here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to debug at this point because the code seems to be right and you should give Django error page information.

I would recommend to set the variable `DEBUG = True` in the settings.py so you can see the Django error page information and start troubleshooting from there.

Post the errors you get so I can update my answer and give you better help.